# What's the difference between vector and array for vertex buffers

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have the following code that renders a square beautifully:

```
            static const VertexPositionColor cubeVertices[] =
            {
                { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
                { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
                { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
                { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ), XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
            };

            D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData = { 0 };
            vertexBufferData.pSysMem = &cubeVertices;
            vertexBufferData.SysMemPitch = 0;
            vertexBufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
            CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc( sizeof( cubeVertices ), D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER );
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateBuffer(
                &vertexBufferDesc,
                &vertexBufferData,
                &m_vertexBuffer[ a ]
                )
                );
```

Now, take this code... which is exact replica with exact same sizeof (96)... but this one uses a vector... why does it render nothing?

```
        FormatCollada* colladaObj = new FormatCollada();
        static const vector<VertexPositionColor> cubeVertices = colladaObj->Format( *geometryData->Collada->LibraryGeometries->Geometry[ a ] );

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData = { 0 };
        vertexBufferData.pSysMem = &cubeVertices;
        vertexBufferData.SysMemPitch = 0;
        vertexBufferData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;
        CD3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc( sizeof( VertexPositionColor ) * cubeVertices.size(), D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER );
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(
            m_deviceResources->GetD3DDevice()->CreateBuffer(
            &vertexBufferDesc,
            &vertexBufferData,
            &m_vertexBuffer[ a ]
            )
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&cubeVertices` does not give you the address of the first element of the `vector`, it gives you the address of the vector object itself. You probably wanted `cubeVertices.data()`.